# Shopware 6 bulk update is very slow

Tags: shopware6

I want to bulk update the price in `product_price`table. So far it is working but it is quite slow. Updating 15 product_prices take about 42 seconds. That is one product every 2,8s (42/15=2,8). Is that expected?

I have tried with 'indexing-behaviour: use-queue-indexing' and 'indexing-behaviour: null'. But there is only a difference of 1sec.

Is there any other way of bulk updating? What is the recommended size of a bulk update entity?

The JSON für the payload looks like this:

```
{
"write-product-price": {
    "entity": "product_price",
    "action": "upsert",
    "payload": [
        {
            "id": "a37554afe6a24649a27c0f56788f2df0",
            "ruleId": "0c7cd6893ba348b2a469d12b64ef3447",
            "productId": "c3d416b54c9f461681290c653f93c7cf",
            "price": [
                {
                    "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                    "net": "1",
                    "gross": "58.9",
                    "linked": true,
                    "listPrice": {
                        "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                        "net": "62.94",
                        "gross": "74.90",
                        "linked": true,
                        "listPrice": null,
                        "extensions": [],
                        "regulationPrice": null
                    }
                }
            ],
            "quantity_start": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "819e482950644b69a330355dfa1e57ff",
            "ruleId": "0c7cd6893ba348b2a469d12b64ef3447",
            "productId": "335894b2df2d4077a2f8bc5c25830c6c",
            "price": [
                {
                    "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                    "net": "1",
                    "gross": "57.9",
                    "linked": true,
                    "listPrice": {
                        "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
                        "net": "59.58",
                        "gross": "70.90",
                        "linked": true,
                        "listPrice": null,
                        "extensions": [],
                        "regulationPrice": null
                    }
                }
            ],
            "quantity_start": 1
        },
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using this URL: '/api/_action/sync' with 'POST';
Mainly I have used this documentation: https://shopware.stoplight.io/

Comment: `use-queue-indexing` should help - how exactly did you try that, maybe there was a problem with switching the index mode.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `APP_ENV` in the `.env` in the root directory? If it isn't `prod`, a large drop off in performance is to be expected. There's a lot of data being collected for debugging purposes in the `dev` environment, that slows down batch write operations.

Other than that, you may want to look at [this guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance/performance-tweaks) regarding performance.

Comment: Thank you. It seems a bit faster. The update of 78 products in `prod` takes 288 seconds instead of 307 seconds in `dev`. But it is still far away from the expected time. It is slower than the csv import in the backend.

I have splitted the prices to be updated in chunks of 20. But now I got an "500 internal server error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded" when upserting the 4th chunk.
Before upserting I always get a new access token. 
Why is this happening?